# Detect USB mouse attach/deattach

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I been searching for a simple way to detect if an USB mouse is attached/deattached to our device, running WinCE 6.0 CF.

I been reading the post " http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/623cfe99-5d44-461c-b9f7-1f84e2c7f241/no-mouse-pointer-wanted-if-no-mouse-is-connected ", but i got stock on how to modify the display drivers.
I also checked into " http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363431(VS.85).aspx "

I wounder if someone could help me. Im using a touchscreen where the mouse cursor should be hidden until an USB mouse is connected, and removed when disconnected. Or if easier at startup the cursor could be shown if mouse is connected. Guess the last alternative is easier. Should be possible to read this information somwhere, but dont know how?

```
public bool isMouseConnected()
{
    //read data from WinCE6.0CF, register, dll or something
    return mouseIsConnected()
}
```

Guess i want to use something like this, but would need an example on how to do this. Normally is google my friends but cant find an example for C#:

```
HDEVNOTIFY WINAPI RegisterDeviceNotification(
  _In_  HANDLE hRecipient,
  _In_  LPVOID NotificationFilter,
  _In_  DWORD Flags);
```

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is [RequestDeviceNotifications()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms919831.aspx) under Windows CE.

There probably won't be a specific example for C#, but you can take a look at [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.registerdevicenotification) which provides C# signatures for similar C functions and extrapolate from there. Microsoft has an online tutorial for [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) that you may find useful.